# IE8: Font-face, limit on size of TTF file?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, web, font-face

Does IE8 have size limit on the size of a font file it will load? For example the following code doesn't seem to work with certain fonts (especially ones over 2MB) but will with smaller fonts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<HEAD>
<style type="text/css"> 
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Symbola'; 
    src: url('Symbola.ttf');
    }
.bars { font-family: 'Symbola'; }
</style>
</HEAD>
<body>
<div class="bars">
&#x23F3;
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 8 does not support TTF fonts in `@font-face`. If it seems to do that for some fonts, the reason is that your computer has the named font as an installed font. So it’s not the size that matters, it’s the formats.

Use e.g. [Fontsquirrel @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to generate different font formats, for cross-browser functionality.

Comment: Wow... Thanks. Didn't even realise the system I was testing on had them installed.